# SWIFT writing to plist is not updating

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, plist

I'm trying to write to the `plist` and I'm using two approaches but none of them work for me.

I'm not getting any errors though and when I print the `paths` I can see that `plist` exist, however you can see from the screenshot that the `plist` it is not getting updated/populated.

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Employee", ofType: "plist")!
let data : NSDictionary = 
["A": [["userid":"1","username":"AAA","usergroupid":"2"], ["userid":"33","username":"ABB","usergroupid":"8"]],
"B": [["userid":"2","username":"BBB","usergroupid":"8"], ["userid":"43","username":"ABC","usergroupid":"8"]] ]

 //first approach
let favoritesDictionary = NSDictionary(object: data, forKey: ("Favorites" as NSString?)!)
print(path)
let succeeded = favoritesDictionary.write(toFile: path, atomically: true)

                
//second approach
let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Employee", ofType: "plist")!
print(bundlePath)
let dictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: bundlePath)
dictionary?.setObject(data, forKey: ("Locations" as NSString?)!)
dictionary?.write(toFile: bundlePath, atomically: true)
```

[image]

Can someone please help?

Comment: It's impossible to write into the application bundle. For obvious reasons it's read-only. To modify the file copy it into the `Documents` folder on the first launch of the app. And don't use the `NSDictionary/NSArray` API to read/write property lists. There is `PropertyListSerialization` or  `PropertyListDecoder`. And don't use `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift at all.

Comment: Many thanks @vadian I didn't know that. I'm very new to Swift and macOS app dev. Is there any example out there showing how I could achieve the above and what you have said?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a short tutorial.

- Create your plist file and put it in the application bundle.
- In `AppDelegate` create a computed property to get the current `Documents` folder and append the file path

  ```
   var employeePlistURL : URL {
       let documentsFolderURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
       return documentsFolderURL.appendingPathComponent("Employee.plist")
   }
  ```
- In `AppDelegate` `applicationWillFinishLaunching` register a key-value pair for the `firstLaunch` flag in `UserDefaults` and copy the plist into the documents folder if the flag is true

  ```
  func applicationWillFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
       let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
       defaults.register(defaults: ["firstLaunch":true])
       if defaults.bool(forKey: "firstLaunch") {
           let sourceFile = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Employee", withExtension: "plist")!
           try? FileManager.default.copyItem(at: sourceFile, to: employeePlistURL)
           defaults.set(false, forKey: "firstLaunch")
       }
   }
  ```
- Wherever you need to read and write the property list create also the computed property and add a property for the dictionary

  ```
  var employees = [String:Any]()
  ```

  and two methods to load and save the data

  ```
   func loadEmployees() {
       do {
           let data = try Data(contentsOf: employeePlistURL)
           guard let plist = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, format: nil) as? [String:Any] else { return }
           employees = plist
       } catch { print(error) }
   }

   func saveEmployees() {
       do {
           let data = try PropertyListSerialization.data(fromPropertyList: employees, format: .binary, options: 0)
           try data.write(to: employeePlistURL)
       } catch { print(error) }
   }
  ```

A better way is to use structs and `PropertyListEncoder/-Decoder` but as the literal dictionary and the screenshot in the question are rather different I provide the common `Dictionary` / `PropertyListSerialization` way.

Comment: Awesome!! :) Many thanks for this. You're re star. Now I need to learn how to keep adding and deleting from employees :)